# How to give column names after count and joins?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

compnaies = ['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Google','Google']
products = ['OS', 'Search', 'E-comm', 'X-box', 'Social Media', 'Android','Search']

df = pd.DataFrame({'company' : compnaies, 'product':products })
```

I do the following operation:

```
 df.groupby('company').product.agg([('count', 'count'), ('product', ', '.join)])



        count   product
company     
Amazon      1   E-comm
Facebook    1   Social Media
Google      3   Search, Android, Search
Microsoft   2   OS, X-box
```

**How to name the columns after the above code instead of count and product:**

Expected Output:

```
company     Number   Product List.
Amazon      1        E-comm
Facebook    1        Social Media
Google      3        Search, Android, Search
Microsoft   2        OS, X-box
```

Expected Output 2:

Expected Output:

```
 company        Number   Product List.            uniquecount uniquevalues
    Amazon      1        E-comm                       1         E-comm
    Facebook    1        Social Media                 2         Social Media
    Google      3        Search, Android, Search      2         Search, Android,
    Microsoft   2        OS, X-box, Search            3         OS, X-box,Search
```

Comment: `final_df.reset_index()` and rename the columns

Comment: @Madhuri I tried but it doesn't work I need to rename two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


def remove_dup(string):
    temp=string.split(',')
    temp=[x.strip() for x in temp]
    return ','.join(set(temp))

compnaies = ['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Google','Google']
products = ['OS', 'Search', 'E-comm', 'X-box', 'Social Media', 'Android','Search']

df = pd.DataFrame({'company' : compnaies, 'product':products })

new_df=df.groupby('company').product.agg([('Number', 'count'), ('Product list', ', '.join)]).reset_index()

#create uniquevalues
new_df['uniquevalues']=new_df['Product list'].apply(remove_dup)

#create uniquecount
new_df['uniquecount']=new_df['uniquevalues'].str.split(',').str.len()
```

Comment: it works How to count the unique values and also print the unique values on the product list can you help?

Comment: what unique values are you referring to ? ,  you want to remove duplicate values in `df['Product List'] `?

Comment: I just added it as Expected output 2

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard answer:

```
df.groupby('company').product.agg([('count', 'count'), ('product', ', '.join)]).rename(columns={"count":"number","product":"product lists"})
```

[Pandas Online help](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once)